# Change database table name for django builtin tables

Tags: django, django-models

How can I do set a custom table name to django builtin tabes?

For example, `migrations`, `content_type` or `admin_log` are stored as:

- django_migrations
- django_content_type
- django_admin_log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to internal django source and add `db_table` attribute to `Meta` class where you need.

[Details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#db-table)